# Finding the density of nitrogen at 0 degrees Celsius and 1 atmosphere

Tags: gas-laws, density

> The density of nitrogen at $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$ and $\pu{1 atm}$ is most nearly equal to which of the following quantities?
> (a) $\pu{0.001 g/L}$; (b) $\pu{0.01 g/L}$; (c) $\pu{0.1 g/L}$;
> (d) $\pu{1 g/L}$; (e) $\pu{10 g/L}$.

The answer is (d), $\pu{1 g L-1}$.

I think this is how you do it, but please correct me if I'm missing something. I didn't end up using the standard molar volume, so this might be incorrect.
$$pV = nRT$$

We know the pressure is $\pu{1 atm}$, the temperature is about $\pu{273 K}$ and $R = 0.08$.

Solving for $\frac {n}{V}$, we find $\frac {n}{V} = \frac {1}{22}$.  Now, this is in moles per litre, so by multiplying by the molar mass of nitrogen (approximately $\pu{28 g mol-1}$), we find that we have about $\pu{1 g}$ per litre as the density.

Comment: "… the following quantities" – These are not "quantities", they are "quantity values", 
"values of a quantity", or simply "values".

Comment: Your approach is correct. But use units whenever needed and follow correct significant figures.

Comment: @FadedGiant  According to my reading of IUPAC's defintion of "quantity" (https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/Q04982), the HW question's use of the term is acceptable:  "The term quantity may refer to a quantity in a general sense, for example length, mass, or to a particular quantity, for example length of a particular rod, mass of a specified object".  Hence quantity could also refer to the density of a particular sample of gas, which is precisely what the HW question is listing.

Comment: Also, "quantity value" and "value" are problematic, since if you take quantity in the first sense IUPAC uses then for, say, "0.01 g/L" the quantity would be "density", the value would be "0.01", and the units would be "g/L".  See, for instance, how NIST distinguishes quantity, value, and units here: https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C24203369&Mask=40 .  Alas, this is inconsistent with how NIST uses "value of quant." here, which seems along the lines you're suggesting:  https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-chapter-7-rules-and-style-conventions-expressing-values

Answer (score 2):

Using the ideal gas law
\begin{align}
  pV &= nRT, &
  \frac nV &= \frac{p}{RT},
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
  T &= \pu{273 K},\\
  p &= \pu{1 atm},\\
  R &= \pu{0.0821 L atm mol-1 K-1},\\
  M(\ce{N2}) &= \pu{28.0 g mol-1},
\end{align}
we get
\begin{align}
  \frac{n}{V} &= 
    \frac{\pu{1 atm}}{\pu{0.0821 L atm//mol K} \times\pu{273 K}},\\
  \frac{n}{V} &= \pu{0.0446 mol//L},
\end{align}
and finally
$$
\rho(\ce{N2}) 
  = \pu{0.0446  mol//L} \times \pu{28  g//mol} 
  = \pu{1.2  g//L}.
$$
Therefore answer (d) is correct.